# How to deal with giant mesh (.obj) SceneKit, Swift?

Tags: swift, scenekit, mesh

I try to show a really big .obj file using SceneKit.

.obj file is 380MB + textures (images) 150 MB.

It takes 2.5 GB of memory:
[image]

2.5 GB - it's 100% crash on iPhones.

How to load mesh (or textures) part by part?

Or load only closest to cameraNode textures?

Or reduce the quality of mesh/textures to make mesh lighter?

Answer (score 0):

This is way over the top when it comes to scenekit. I recommend, do not use models bigger than 10MB in size. Make your textures 1024x1024 (in rare case 2048 would be okay too). Also keep in mind, how many objects you want to display at the same time. Try to hold your memory usage below 500 MB, if possible. This should be enough for most iPhones, iPads. Regarding MacOS this may vary, depending on the hardware you are using.